# link is stored in variable and want to get a parameter from it in php

Tags: php, mysql, url

I want to fetch the value of 'id' parameter from URL which is stored in variable. The link is stored in variable because the link fetched from database table is stored in variable.

Can any one suggest a solution in PHP?

Comment: Please, post an example of the URL!!! It is something like *http://yoursite.com/somepage.php?id=123*??

Comment: you can split link from our basic function after fetch from DB

Comment: the url is not fixed. it varies from different sites. not all sites are fixed. some varies

Comment: how to get id from itunes.apple.com/app/id728530735?mt=8 the id is 7258...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$url = "http://yoursite.com?id=1345";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $output);
echo $output['id'];
```

Hope that solves your problem.

for itunes, you can use

```
$idpos = strpos ($url, 'id');
```

to get the position of id and then extract the id substring by using that

```
$id = substr($url, $idpos+2, strpos($url, '?')-($idpos+2));
```

Now this should work.

Comment: Thank u ,for quick answer....i will apply to all different sites url and let u know

Comment: Yes, and feel free to let me know, if you run into any problem.

Comment: There is no id parameter in the url's query string. The method above works for the parameters in query string.

Comment: You might need to apply checks, to get the ids in different ways from different sites.

Comment: for itunes, you can use 
$idpos = strpos ( string $url, 'id');
to get the position of id and then extract the id substring by using that 
$id = substr($url, $idpos+2, strlen($url)-strpos($url, '?'));
I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: If all your urls is like this : `itunes.apple.com/app/id[0-9]{6}` you can use `substr` or `preg_match` for get `[0-9]{6}` area.

Comment: Mubashir Abbas - 
eg -https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id836071680?mt=8
$idpos = strpos ( string $url, 'id'); //32
 $id = substr($url, $idpos+2, strlen($url)-strpos($url, '?')); //(url,34,48-43)
it is copying only 5 digit remaining digits is still needed to copy

Comment: please check the updated answer.. the comment was untested.

Comment: Mubashir Abbas - 
partial id is getting. Unable to getting whole id.
substr($url,34,48-43).     
so only 5 digit is getting from 9digit id

Comment: rohan, plz check the updated code in the answer.. not in the comment. I have UPDATED the answer..

Comment: this is the code now
$idpos = $idpos+2;
$qpos = strpos($url, '?');
$idlength = $qpos - $idlength;
$id = substr($url, $idpos+2, $idlength);

Comment: yeah it works Mubashir Abbas -(little updates)
$idpos = strpos ($url, 'id');
$id = substr($url, $idpos+2, strpos($url, '?')-($idpos+2));